# Typescript error when trying to implement nested reactive forms in angular

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

i'm getting a typescript error: `Typescript error when trying to implement nested reactive forms in angular.`

I can't understand at what part it becomes an AbstractControl if i'm sending a FormGroup from the beggining

i have this parent component:

```
import { Component, EventEmitter, Inject, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { FormBuilder, FormGroup, Validators, FormArray } from '@angular/forms';
import { ClientsService } from 'src/app/services/clients.service';
import { MAT_DIALOG_DATA } from '@angular/material/dialog';
import { ContactFormComponent } from '../contact-form/contact-form.component';

@Component({
  selector: 'client-form',
  templateUrl: './client-form.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./client-form.component.css']
})

export class ClientFormComponent implements OnInit {

  form!: FormGroup;
  submitted = new EventEmitter();

  client: any = {};
  
  constructor(
    private fb: FormBuilder, 
    private ClientSrv: ClientsService, 
    @Inject(MAT_DIALOG_DATA) data: any) {
      if(data) {
        this.client = data;
      }
  };
  
  ngOnInit() {
    this.createForm();
  }

  get contactsArray(): FormArray {
    return this.form?.get('contacts') as FormArray;
  }
  
    
  createForm(): void {
    this.form = this.fb.group({
      'id': [this.client.id],
      'client_name': [this.client.client_name, [Validators.required, Validators.minLength(8)]],
      'client_id': [this.client.client_id, Validators.required],
      'address': [this.client.address, Validators.required],
      'company_email': [this.client.company_email, [Validators.required, Validators.email]],
      'contacts': this.fb.array([ ContactFormComponent.createContactItem() ])
    });
  }
    
  submitForm(update: string): any {
    console.log(this.form.value)
  }
}
```

and another component that is `ContactFormComponent.createContactItem()` which goes into the FormArray:

```
import { Component, Input } from '@angular/core';
import { FormBuilder, FormGroup, Validators } from '@angular/forms';

@Component({
  selector: 'contact-form',
  templateUrl: './contact-form.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./contact-form.component.css']
})

export class ContactFormComponent {

  @Input() contactForm!: FormGroup;

  static createContactItem(): FormGroup {
    return new FormBuilder().group({
      'name': [null, [Validators.required]],
      'phone': [null, [Validators.required]],
      'email': [null, [Validators.required, Validators.email]],
    });
  }
  

}
```

this is the parent component template where i get the error:

```
<mat-dialog-content>
  <form [formGroup]="form" (ngSubmit)="client.id ? submitForm('update') : submitForm('new')" autocomplete="false">
    <h3>Client Info</h3>
    <form-input name="client_name" type="text" formControlName="client_name" ></form-input>
    <form-input-errors [control]="form.get('client_name')"></form-input-errors>
    <br />
    <form-input name="client_id" type="text" formControlName="client_id" ></form-input>
    <form-input-errors [control]="form.get('client_id')"></form-input-errors>
    <br />
    <form-input name="address" type="text" formControlName="address" ></form-input>
    <form-input-errors [control]="form.get('address')"></form-input-errors>
    <br />
    <form-input name="company_email" type="email" formControlName="company_email" ></form-input>
    <form-input-errors [control]="form.get('company_email')"></form-input-errors>
    <br />
    <h3>Contacts</h3>
    <ng-container *ngFor="let contactForm of contactsArray.controls">
      <!-- // HERE I GET THE ERROR Type 'AbstractControl<any, any>' is missing the following properties from type 'FormGroup<any>' -->
      <contact-form [contactForm]="contactForm" ></contact-form> 
    </ng-container>
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-sm btn-primary" [disabled]="form.invalid">{{ client.id ? "Update" : "Create" }}</button>
  </form>  
</mat-dialog-content>
```

i could only get it to work if i change in child component the variable to `Any` instead of `FormGroup` but that would be me not understanding why it is happening. Please help, what is the correct way of doing this. thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue you're having here is that `FormGroup.get()` returns an `AbstractControl` because it can be a `FormGroup`, `FormControl` or `FormArray`. I'd suggest that you change the input type to `AbstractControl` and then either cast or narrow it to a `FormGroup` where necessary. Does that make sense?

Comment: yeah it makes sense everything works as expected when i change `@Input()` variable type to `any` . but i see on web examples that it works for them as `FormGroup` which led me to believe i'm doing something wrong. does this mean they are just not using 'strict' mode? ..  can i change the getter maybe in a way that it will know it's a formGroup? thanks for the answer.

Comment: You can find more info in the [TypeScript documentation](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/narrowing.html) about narrowing.

Answer (score 1):

You can change your Input using a setter

```
contactForm!: FormGroup; //<--declare the contactForm
@Input('contactForm') set _contactForm(value:AbstractControl){
   this.contactForm=value as FormGroup  //"cast" the AbstractControl
}
```

Before strict mode, the compilator not take account this

From Angular 16 you can also use [transform](https://angular.io/api/core/Input#transform)

```
@Input({transform:(value:any)=>value as FormGroup}) contactForm!:FormGroup
```