# Angular: Type AbstractControl<any> is not assignable to type FormControl

Tags: angular, typescript, form-control

I have a child component with an `input` tag

```html
<input [formControl]="control">
```

*component.ts* file

```js
@Input() control: FormControl;
```

And using it in the parent as

```html
<app-input [control]="f['email']"></app-input>
                      ~~~~~~~~~~
```

*component.ts* file

```js
public form: FormGroup;

constructor(
    private fb: FormBuilder,
  ) {
    this.form = this.fb.group({
      email: ['', [
        Validators.email,
        Validators.required
      ]],
    });
}

get f() {
    return this.form.controls;
}
```

But it is giving an error in the HTML `control` assignment.

```
Type AbstractControl<any> is not assignable to type FormControl
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
get f() {
  return this.form.controls as {[key: string]: FormControl } ;
}
```

Because form groups and arrays can contain groups, arrays or controls, they return abstract controls. You have to explicitly state they are controls.

Answer (score 0):

What you can do is the following:

```
public form: FormGroup = this.fb.group({
  email: ['', [
    Validators.email,
    Validators.required
  ]],
});

constructor(private fb: FormBuilder) 
{}`
```

Then in the parent html: `<app-input [control]="form.controls.email"></app-input>`

This way the form control values are available during development as types

Comment: It still has the same error.

Comment: I have it working like this. You maybe tried this? https://github.com/ngx-formly/ngx-formly/issues/2842#issuecomment-931865585 

Also is your ngModule set with the correct modules like: FormsModule and ReactiveFormsModule

Also check this one: https://github.com/primefaces/primeng/issues/9636 

This is my tsconfig.json for the angular part },
  "angularCompilerOptions": {
    "enableI18nLegacyMessageIdFormat": false,
    "strictInjectionParameters": true,
    "strictPropertyInitialization":false,
    "strictInputAccessModifiers": true,
    "strictTemplates": true
  }

Comment: @LeroyMeijer, it's problem with "strict mode". The clasic solution is use a getter, in Angular 16 you can use transform (see this [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76570807/typescript-error-when-trying-to-implement-nested-reactive-forms-in-angular/76571571#76571571) -is related to a formGroup but you can use the same with a FormControl. BTW Threr'e another aproach that it's use viewProvider, like this [another SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73455294/how-do-i-get-access-to-from-control-from-another-component-in-angular/73457780#73457780)

Comment: Good find @Eliseo, I'm using Angular 16.1.3 with the strict settings like my comment above and it's working. Thanks for this improvement